# Google Analytics ecommerce tracking referral issue with paypal payment gateway

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, paypal, payment-gateway, universal-analytics

I having a problem on ecommerce tracking.

The current shopping flow:

1. User clicked the ads from social media -facebook and directed to our site.
2. User make order on our site.
3. User make payment:-
    a. if user make a direct payment - bank wire 
          - Google analytic has logged a event on Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium. 
            facebook.com / referral  -- Revenue
    b. else if user make a paypal payment, user will be redirected to paypal.com to complete the payment and redirected to our site.

   - Google analytic has logged a event on Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium. 
          (direct) / (none)  -- Revenue

The problem is, how do I solve this issue, to have the whole transaction into an event ?
           Facebook  -->  domain.com  --> Paypal --> domain.com
The result I wish to have an event :
Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium. 
             facebook.com / referral  -- Revenue
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should keep the return\thank you page after the payment is processed.

Then add your gateway payment websites in Referral Exclusion list. In that case, `paypal.com`

It won't be perfect (lot of people miss the last thank you page), but still better. If you see too many discrepancies between GA and your CRM, think about implementing paypal on-site payment.

Comment: it does redirect to thank you page after the payment is done, but GA just recorded as direct payment :/

Comment: Most of the time it'll work. So look carefully only to data after you add `paypal.com` to referral exclusion list. Look for other code in your website that can interfere and broke reports, like a redirection (if you are not linking directly to your thank you page). Try also to add url parameter `?utm_nooverride=1` at the end of your thank you page (modify it in paypal).

Comment: @lucgenti I guess the `?utm_nooverride=1` parameter should be in your answer - because that is the key thought.